# MATLAB Combining Date and Hour from two cell columns

Tags: matlab, date, plot

I'm trying to plot hourly data. The issue is that the date is in one column of the cell array while the hour is in the next column. How can I plot the data with the x-axis considering both the date and the hour? I'm thinking the best way would be to combine the two columns and use that as my x.

```
% Plot data for the month of June, 2007

    % Uses the FileExchange file addaxes.m to plot 3 different y axes to
    % account for the different units
clear
clc

load WI_200706_Pollution.mat;
%% Order of Columns
% 5.    State Code  
% 6.    County Code 
% 7.    Site Num    
% 13.   Date GMT    
% 14.   24 Hour GMT 
% 17.   Sample Measurement  

%% Sort data by State Code, County Code, Site Code, Date GMT, Hour GMT
% PM25
PM25_State = sortrows(PM25,5);
PM25_County = sortrows(PM25_State,6);
PM25_Site = sortrows(PM25_County,7);
PM25_Date = sortrows(PM25_Site,13);
PM25_Hour = sortrows(PM25_Date, 14);

% SO2
SO2_State = sortrows(SO2,5);
SO2_County = sortrows(SO2_State,6);
SO2_Site = sortrows(SO2_County,7);
SO2_Date = sortrows(SO2_Site,13);
SO2_Hour = sortrows(SO2_Date, 14);

% Pull out data 
PM25_data = PM25_Hour(:,17); % ug/L3
NO2_data = NO2_Hour(:,17); % ppb
CO_data = CO_Hour(:,17); % ppm
O3_data = O3_Hour(:,17); % ppm
SO2_data = SO2_Hour(:,17); % ppb

clearvars -except -regexp _data _Hour % Clear all variables except the sorted _Hour files and the _data files

%%%%%%%
%% Plot PM2.5 daily data
% Axis
DateString = PM25_Hour(2:end,11); % Pull out dates
formatIn = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
x1 = datenum(DateString,formatIn); % Convert to datnum
y1 = PM25_data(2:end); % Plot data

%% Plot SO2 hourly data
% Axis
date = datenum(SO2_Hour(2:end, 11)); 
hour = datenum(SO2_Hour(2:end, 12));
DateString = datenum(strcat(date, hour), 'yyyy-mm-ddHH:MM'); % Pull out dates
x5 = datenum(DateString); % Convert to datnum
y5 = SO2_data(2:end); % Plot data

% Convert cells to double
y1 = str2double(y1);
y5 = str2double(y5);

% Plot
h = figure; % To make the figure not show up, use 'h = figure('visible', 'off')';
plot(x5, y5, 'k', 'LineWidth', 1, 'Marker', 'o'); % Black line of width 2. Circular marker of color blue
addaxis(x1, y1);

addaxislabel(1,'ppb');
addaxislabel(2,'ug/CL');

grid on; % Turn on grid for plot
legend('PM2.5 (ug/CL', 'SO2 (ppb)');
```

The code has been shortened to include only two of the five variables I'm looking at. PM2.5 is daily data, so there's no problem with that. With SO2, I'm trying to combine the date and time under the 'Plot SO2 hourly data' part. Right now, I'm getting this error:

```
Error using datenum
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to
    date number.
```

If I don't combine date and time, I get a bunch of dots going up vertically for each day. How can I still keep the x-axis daily for PM2.5, but allow the SO2 to spread out over the hours of the day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is invalid, because `2000-12-111:00` could be `2000-12-11` at `1:00` or `2000-12-1` at `11:00`. Use a separator.

If this is not the error: What is the input datenum failes at? Try `dbstop if error` then it stops at the right line.

---

Update this fixes the error, there is no reason to convert date and hour to double:

```
date = SO2_Hour(2:end, 11); 
hour = SO2_Hour(2:end, 12);

DateString = datenum(strcat(date,'-', hour), 'yyyy-mm-dd-HH:MM'); % Pull out dates
```

Comment: How do I use a separator? Just adding a '-' doesn't change anything substantial. The error occurs right after `DateString = datenum(strcat...`

Comment: What is input of datenum?

Comment: Here's the dropbox link to my script (it's a longer script, but same idea - I just have a few more variables in the middle where I haven't tried to combine date and time yet) and the .mat file with the data. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hpjelnbzf9m069h/_wef_rKA0W

Comment: The input to datenum is a cell array.

Comment: you should definitely learn to use the debugger. date and hour are cells of doubles, using strcat for doubles has no usefull output in this case. Answer updated.